# Problem of building and rolling dices

Tags: probability, dice

Assume that you are on the ground floor of a building with 100 floors. You have a dice with 6 faces with the number 1 to 6 on the faces. You are playing a game, you will be the winner if you can reach the 60th floor or higher. The way you go is:

You roll the dice:

The result is 1 or 2 then you go down 1 floor.
The result is from 3 to 5, you go up 1 floor.
If the result is 6, you can roll again, the you will go up the number of floor as the number you get.
You can go 1oo times.

Notice:

For some reason, you need to go back to the ground floor. this -probability for this 0.1%.
No negative floor, It means that if you are on the ground floor, and you roll the 1 or 2 faces, you will be still on the ground floor.
Calculate the probability of the winning?

Many assumptions make me confuse. I don't know how to deal with the assumption "For some reason, you need to go back to the ground floor. this -probability for this 0.1%"

Comment: Avoiding basements, the average change is +3/4 floor per roll.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I haven't figured it all out yet, but I computed the expected value floor change due to a die roll to be 3/4 of a floor, assuming you're not near the first floor. So as a rough estimate, it should take 80 rolls to win, so the answer should be a high probability.

Comment: I thnk so, we will have a high probability